# getDrawable from resources

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want retrieve the drawable from drawable folder by my own properties instead to use R.drawable

How can i achieve this ?

```
public void updateLanguageImg(String img)
 {


      Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.);
               // i want retrieve the img String here
      ImageView imageV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageLangue);
      imageV.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

 }
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood properly the question, and according to the parameter received in the method, you want to call a resource by its string name, so if that's correct this is what you have to do:

"context.getResources().getIdentifier("bitmapName","folderName",this.class.getPackageName())"

where: folderName could be ("raw", "drawable" etc...)

This will return the identifierNumber which is what you have already, and you can use the method in stead, something like this:

int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("bitmapName","folderName",this.class.getPackageName();

Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), id);

Regards!

Comment: You would also need a failover if the resource is not found